# NodeJS: Converting values

Tags: arrays, node.js, if-statement

Please find the below code;

```
for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                    if(obj[temp[i]]!=undefined){
                        if(obj[temp[i]].toUpperCase()=="ON" || obj[temp[i]].toUpperCase()=="LOW"){
                        temp[temp[i]] = 0;
                        temp.timestamp = obj.timestamp;
                        paramCount++;
                    }}}
```

In above code in [temp[i]] we are passing some Integer values like (34.5,55,45) and some places string like (ON,OFF,on,off),so I have used .toUpperCase() function but its showing error while fetching integer values.

I want that it should take string values like (ON,OFF,on,off) as well as integer.
I am New in NODEJS please help for same.

Comment: As far as I can understand you want to differentiate between your integer and string value inside your if condition ??

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate between the integers and string inside your if condition use `typeof`

Use

`if(typeof obj[temp[i]] === 'string')`

before

`if(obj[temp[i]].toUpperCase()=="ON" || obj[temp[i]].toUpperCase()=="LOW")`

It will not raise an exception in case of integer values.

Comment: but one more condition is there if it is "ON" "LOW" "on" it will display 1.And if it is "OFF" "HIGH" "off" it will display 0.So if we write string than how we will check the condition.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the same condition but before your if condition so that it will differentiate between your string and integers and will not raise an exception.